# How to update a container only?

Tags: kubernetes

I am working locally with minikube and every time i make a change on the code, i delete the service (and the deployment) and create a new one.

This operation generate a new IP for each container so i also need to update my frontend, and also to insert new data in my db container, since i loose every data every time i delete the service.

It’s way too much wasted time to work efficiently.

I would like to know if there is a way to update a container without generating new IPs, and without deleting the pod (because i don't want to delete my db container everytime i update the backend code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to update the existing [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) with a new image without necessity to delete it.

Imagine we have a YAML [file](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/master/content/en/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml) with the Deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

To run this deployment, run the following command:

```
$ kubectl create -f nginx-deployment.yaml --record
```

(`--record` - appends the current command to the annotations of the created or updated resource. This is useful for future reviews, such as investigating which commands were executed in each Deployment revision, and for making a rollback.)

To see the Deployment rollout status, run

```
$ kubectl rollout status deployment/nginx-deployment
```

To update nginx image version, just run the command:

```
$ kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1
```

Or you can edit existing Deployment with the command:

```
$ kubectl edit deployment/nginx-deployment
```

To see the status of the Deployment update process, run the command:

```
$ kubectl rollout status deployment/nginx-deployment
Waiting for rollout to finish: 2 out of 3 new replicas have been updated...
deployment "nginx-deployment" successfully rolled out
```

or

```
$ kubectl get deployments
NAME               DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-deployment   3         3         3            3           36s
```

Each time you update the Deployment, it updates the Pods by creating new ReplicaSet, scaling it to 3 replicas, and scaling down old ReplicaSet to 0. If you update the Deployment again during the previous update in progress, it starts to create new ReplicaSet immediately, without waiting for completion of the previous update.

```
$ kubectl get rs
NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
nginx-deployment-1180356465   3         3         3       4s
nginx-deployment-2538420311   0         0         0       56s
```

If you made a typo while editing the Deployment (for example, nginx:1.91) you can rollback it to the previous good version.
First, check the revisions of this deployment:

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment/nginx-deployment
deployments "nginx-deployment"
REVISION    CHANGE-CAUSE
1           kubectl create -f nginx-deployment.yaml --record
2           kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1
3           kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.91
```

Because we recorded the command while creating this Deployment using --record, we can easily see the changes we made in each revision.

To see the details of each revision, run:

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment/nginx-deployment --revision=2
deployments "nginx-deployment" revision 2
  Labels:       app=nginx
          pod-template-hash=1159050644
  Annotations:  kubernetes.io/change-cause=kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1
  Containers:
   nginx:
    Image:      nginx:1.9.1
    Port:       80/TCP
     QoS Tier:
        cpu:      BestEffort
        memory:   BestEffort
    Environment Variables:      <none>
  No volumes.
```

Now you can rollback to the previous version using command:

```
$ kubectl rollout undo deployment/nginx-deployment
deployment "nginx-deployment" rolled back
```

Or you can rollback to a specific version:

```
$ kubectl rollout undo deployment/nginx-deployment --to-revision=2
deployment "nginx-deployment" rolled back
```

For more information, please read the part of Kubernetes documentation related to [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)

Comment: The ``kubectl set image`` command is what i was looking for! But the weird thing is i can't put the ``docker build``and ``kubectl set image`` commands into a shell script (i see the success messages but the container doesn't change, like if it was build in another "environment"), any idea about why ?

Comment: Perhaps no correct authentication configured for user account that runs a script.

Answer (score 1):

Use kops and create a production like cluster in AWS on the free tier. 
In order to fix this you need to make sure you use a loadbalancer for your frontends. Create a service for your db container exposing the port so your frontends can reach it, and put that in your manifest for your frontends so its static. Service discovery will take care of the ip address and your containers will automatically connect to the ports. You can also setup persistent storage for your DBs. When you update your frontend code, use this to update your containers so nothing will change.

kubectl set image deployment/helloworld-deployment basicnodeapp=buildmystartup/basicnodeapp:2

Here is how I would do a state-full app in production AWS using wordpress for an example.

```
###############################################################################
#
# Creating a stateful app with persistent storage and front end containers
#
###############################################################################

* Here is how you create a stateful app using volumes and persistent storage for production.

* To start off we can automate the storage volume creation for our mysql server with a storage object and persistent volume claim like so:

$ cat storage.yml
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  zone: us-east-1b

  $ cat pv-claim.yml
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: db-storage
    annotations:
      volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "standard"
  spec:
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 8Gi

* Lets go ahead and create these so they are ready for our deployment of mysql

$ kubectl create -f storage.yml
storageclass "standard" created


$ kubectl create -f pv-claim.yml
persistentvolumeclaim "db-storage" created

* Lets also create our secrets file that will be needed for mysql and wordpress

$ cat wordpress-secrets.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: wordpress-secrets
type: Opaque
data:
  db-password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
  # random sha1 strings - change all these lines
  authkey: MTQ3ZDVhMTIzYmU1ZTRiMWQ1NzUyOWFlNWE2YzRjY2FhMDkyZGQ4OA==
  loggedinkey: MTQ3ZDVhMTIzYmU1ZTRiMWQ1NzUyOWFlNWE2YzRjY2FhMDkyZGQ4OQ==
  secureauthkey: MTQ3ZDVhMTIzYmU1ZTRiMWQ1NzUyOWFlNWE2YzRjY2FhMDkyZGQ5MQ==
  noncekey: MTQ3ZDVhMTIzYmU1ZTRiMWQ1NzUyOWFlNWE2YzRjY2FhMDkyZGQ5MA==
  authsalt: MTQ3ZDVhMTIzYmU1ZTRiMWQ1NzUyOWFlNWE2YzRjY2FhMDkyZGQ5Mg==
  secureauthsalt: MTQ3ZDVhMTIzYmU1ZTRiMWQ1NzUyOWFlNWE2YzRjY2FhMDkyZGQ5Mw==
  loggedinsalt: MTQ3ZDVhMTIzYmU1ZTRiMWQ1NzUyOWFlNWE2YzRjY2FhMDkyZGQ5NA==
  noncesalt: MTQ3ZDVhMTIzYmU1ZTRiMWQ1NzUyOWFlNWE2YzRjY2FhMDkyZGQ5NQ==

$ kubectl create -f wordpress-secrets.yml



* Take note of the names we assigned. We will need these for the mysql deployment

* We created the storage in us-east-1b so lets set a node label for our node in that AZ so our deployment is pushed to that node and can attach our volume.

$ kubectl label nodes ip-172-20-48-74.ec2.internal storage=mysql
node "ip-172-20-48-74.ec2.internal" labeled

* Here is our mysql pod definition. Notice at the bottom we use a nodeSelector
* We will need to use that same one for our deployment so it can reach us-east-1b


$ cat wordpress-db.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: wordpress-db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: wordpress-db
  template:
    metadata:
      name: wordpress-db
      labels:
        app: wordpress-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        args:
          - "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found"
        ports:
        - name: mysql-port
          containerPort: 3306
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: wordpress-secrets
                key: db-password
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
          name: mysql-storage
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: db-storage
      nodeSelector:
        storage: mysql

* Before we go on to the deployment lets expose a service on port 3306 so wordpress can connect.

$ cat wordpress-db-service.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-db
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: wordpress-db
  type: NodePort



$ kubectl create -f wordpress-db-service.yml
service "wordpress-db" created

* Now lets work on the deployment. We are going to use EFS to save all our pictures and blog posts so lets create that on us-east-1b also

* So first lets create our EFS NFS share

$ aws efs create-file-system --creation-token 1
{
    "NumberOfMountTargets": 0,
    "SizeInBytes": {
        "Value": 0
    },
    "CreationTime": 1501863105.0,
    "OwnerId": "812532545097",
    "FileSystemId": "fs-55ed701c",
    "LifeCycleState": "creating",
    "CreationToken": "1",
    "PerformanceMode": "generalPurpose"
}

$ aws efs create-mount-target --file-system-id fs-55ed701c --subnet-id subnet-7405f010 --security-groups sg-ffafb98e
{
    "OwnerId": "812532545097",
    "MountTargetId": "fsmt-a2f492eb",
    "IpAddress": "172.20.53.4",
    "LifeCycleState": "creating",
    "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-cac952dd",
    "FileSystemId": "fs-55ed701c",
    "SubnetId": "subnet-7405f010"
}


* Before we launch the deployment lets make sure our mysql server is up and connected to the volume we created

$ kubectl get pvc
NAME         STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
db-storage   Bound     pvc-82c889c3-7929-11e7-8ae1-02fa50f1a61c   8Gi        RWO           standard       51m

* ok status bound means our container is connected to the volume.

* Now lets launch the wordpress frontend of two replicas.

$ cat wordpress-web.yml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wordpress
        image: wordpress:4-php7.0
        # uncomment to fix perm issue, see also https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2630
        # command: ['bash', '-c', 'chown', 'www-data:www-data', '/var/www/html/wp-content/upload', '&&', 'apache2', '-DFOREGROUND']
        ports:
        - name: http-port
          containerPort: 80
        env:
          - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: wordpress-secrets
                key: db-password
          - name: WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: wordpress-secrets
                key: authkey
          - name: WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: wordpress-secrets
                key: loggedinkey
          - name: WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: wordpress-secrets
                key: secureauthkey
          - name: WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: wordpress-secrets
                key: noncekey
          - name: WORDPRESS_AUTH_SALT
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: wordpress-secrets
                key: authsalt
          - name: WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: wordpress-secrets
                key: secureauthsalt
          - name: WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: wordpress-secrets
                key: loggedinsalt
          - name: WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: wordpress-secrets
                key: noncesalt
          - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
            value: wordpress-db
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
          name: uploads
      volumes:
      - name: uploads
        nfs:
          server: us-east-1b.fs-55ed701c.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
          path: /

* Notice we put together a string for the NFS share.
* AZ.fs-id.Region.amazonaws.com

* Now lets create our deployment.

$ kubectl create -f wordpress-web.yml

$ cat wordpress-web-service.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: http-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: wordpress
  type: LoadBalancer


* And now the load balancer for our two nodes

$ kubectl create -f wordpress-web-service.yml


* Now lets find our ELB and create a Route53 DNS name for it.

$ kubectl get services

$ kubectl describe service wordpress
Name:           wordpress
Namespace:      default
Labels:         <none>
Annotations:        <none>
Selector:       app=wordpress
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         100.70.74.90
LoadBalancer Ingress:   acf99336a792b11e78ae102fa50f1a61-516654231.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:           <unset> 80/TCP
NodePort:       <unset> 30601/TCP
Endpoints:      100.124.209.16:80,100.94.7.215:80
Session Affinity:   None
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubObjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------          -------
  38m       38m     1   service-controller          Normal      CreatingLoadBalancer    Creating load balancer
  38m       38m     1   service-controller          Normal      CreatedLoadBalancer Created load balancer

  $ kubectl get deployments
  NAME                   DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
  wordpress-deployment   2         2         2            2           2m


  $ kubectl get pods
  NAME                                    READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
  sysdig-agent-4sxv2                      1/1       Running             0          3d
  sysdig-agent-nb2wk                      1/1       Running             0          3d
  sysdig-agent-z42zj                      1/1       Running             0          3d
  wordpress-db-79z87                      1/1       Running             0          54m
  wordpress-deployment-2971992143-c8gg4   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          1m
  wordpress-deployment-2971992143-h36v1   1/1       Running             0          1m
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your front-end, use DNS names instead of IP addresses to reach your backend. This will save you from rebuilding your front-end app every time you deploy your backend.

That being said, there is no need to delete your service just to deploy a new version of your backend. In fact, you just need to update your deployment, making it refer to the new docker image you have built using the latest code for your backend.

Finally, as long as I understand, you have both your application and your database inside the same Pod. This is not a good practice, you should separate them in order not to cause a downtime in your database when you deploy a new version of your code.

As a sidenote, not sure if this is the case, but if you are using minikube as a development environment you're probably doing it wrong. You should use docker alone with volume binding, but that's out of scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually need to solve 2 issues:

1. Do not restart the service. Restart only your pod. Then the service won't change its IP address.
2. Database and your application don't need to be 2 containers in the same pod. They should be 2 separate pods. Then you need another service to expose the database to your application.

So the final solution should be like this:

1. database pod - runs once, never restarted during development.
2. database service - created once, never restarted.
3. application pod - this is the only thing you will reload when the application code is changed. It needs to access the database, so you write literally "database-service:3306" or something like this in your application. "database-service" here is the name of the service you created in (2).
4. application service - created once, never restarted. You access the application from outside of minikube by using IP address of this service.